# What is Natural Navigation?

Tags: control, navigation, path-planning

While going through [this Page](https://www.transbotics.com/learning-center/guidance-navigation) on different types of navigations used in AGV's for Industrial Environments. I came across natural navigation which claims to reduce installation time and cost for the AGV by getting rid of reflectors, localization markers.

So what is Natural Navigation? How does it work? How does it handle Localization and Path Planning? what kind of sensors does it need?
Are there any open source implementations of this method.

Any links to research papers/tutorials are welcome

Answer (score 2):

What they describe is normally called (markerless) SLAM. Mostly implemented with laser scanners (from Sick, Velodyne, Pepperl&Fuchs,...). Classic implementations are gmapping, cartographer or hector-slam.

Comment: Can you point out any specific resource regarding natural navigation?

Thank you for actively answering the questions

Comment: forget this name. Just look for SLAM and you will find tons of information.